# integral equality related to Nussbaum functions

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, supremum-and-infimum

Consider a real function $f: \mathrm{R} \to \mathrm{R}$, $f$ is piecewise right continuous, and this pair of equations:

$$
\sup_{x> a} \frac 1 {x-a} \int_a^x f(s) \, ds = \phantom{-}\infty \tag1\\
\inf_{x> a} \frac 1 {x-a} \int_a^x f(s) \, ds = -\infty. 
$$

A remark I found states:
**If (1) holds for some $a \in \mathrm{R}$, then it holds for all $a \in \mathrm{R}$.**

I need help proving this remark.

I see two possible ways to tackle this problem:

1. using the (first) mean value theorem for definite integrals
2. using the fundamental theorem of calculus

I am, however, in both cases not sure how to deal with the required **closed** intervals and the **open** interval $(x, \infty)$ from the supremum/infimum.

Hopefully, someone can give me a hint.

Comment: What are you assuming about $f$?

Comment: There isn't given any specification, but I guess piecewise continuity would be a good assumption? If possible, I would not like to assume differentiability.

These equations originate from a context, where a class of functions $f$ is defined through (1).

Comment: Good, see my answer then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note first that
$$
\sup_{x> a} \frac 1 {x-a} \int_a^x f(s) \, ds = +\infty
$$
if and only if there exists a sequence $x_k\nearrow+\infty$ such that
$$
\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac 1 {x_k-a} \int_a^{x_k} f(s) \, ds = +\infty.
$$
Now take any $b\in\mathbb R$. Then 
$$
\begin{split}
\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac 1 {x_k-b} \int_b^{x_k} f(s) \, ds
&= 
\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac {x_k-a} {x_k-b} \cdot\frac 1 {x_k-a} \left(\int_a^{x_k} f(s) \, ds -\int_a^b f(s) \, ds\right)\\
&=\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac 1 {x_k-a} \int_a^{x_k} f(s) \, ds= +\infty
\end{split}
$$
since
$$
\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac {x_k-a} {x_k-b}=1
$$
and
$$
\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac 1 {x_k-a} \int_a^b f(s) \, ds=0.
$$

You can do the same for the infimum.

Comment: One followup question: when you introduce the sequence $x_k$, why do you require it to increase to $\infty$? If (1) holds for some (fixed) $a$, can't the function under the supremum be singular at some point $b > a$ producing the supremum $\infty$?

Comment: You answered that you want a piecewise continuous function, so that doesn't happen.

Comment: Almost thought so. I just wanted to confirm it.